# Why does OxyPlot.PngExporter.Export not export a .png file

Tags: file, plot, export, png, oxyplot

I try to export an `Oxyplot` `PlotModel` to `.png`

I tried like so:

```
Stream stream = File.Create(path);
var pngExporter = new PngExporter { Width = 600, Height = 400, Background = OxyColors.White };
PngExporter.Export(this.PlotModel, stream, 800, 600);
```

The output file is a .File type.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file extension is .File, it means the file is missing `*.png` and is therefore not readable by windows. 
You could try adding the file extension like this `Stream stream = File.Create(path+ ".png");`